# How do I include image directories and files in my JavaFX build using Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea, javafx, javafx-8

I can not seem to figure this out.

I have marked some directories outside of my src folder as "resources" in the module settings of the project structure.

When I build the artifact those directories are not included or the files within them.

My directory structure is:

```
/myApp
    -src/com/org/myapp
    -theme //this is an image folder
    -profilepics //this is an image folder
    -genimages //this is an image folder
```

I have tried marking the directories as source folders as well as marking the myApp directory as source.

Comment: Put the images in the package of the class that you are loading the images in, then reference the image using `/imagename.png`

Comment: what if I want to have the images divided into directories? when I make a package in intellij it does not give me an option to make directories inside of that. Also, I reference the images from many different classes.

Comment: also, the user will add images through the app so i need a directory right?

Comment: Then make a package to store images, and reference them relative to the current class

Comment: You can't add things into packages at runtime (at least, not without some fairly serious hacks that would be pretty fragile) - imagine what happens once the app is bundled as a jar file. You should define a specific folder on the file system for user images. You should be able to configure IntelliJ to deploy resources from other folders - I'm not an IntelliJ user though. Look for something like "source folder" configuration, and see if there is somewhere to configure filename patterns for what is deployed from there.

Answer (score 0):

Had this same issue, here's how I fixed it:

- Open up the project inside IntelliJ, click on Build -> Build Artifacts..
- Select your artifact, and then on the 'Actions' submenu, click 'Edit'
- In 'Output layout', click on '+', add then pick 'Directory content'
- Select your images folder, click 'OK', and then save the changes

Also, check how the images are used in the .fxml files (if they are shown to be inside a folder, you may need to put the images inside a folder too -> after selecting the images folder in the artifact menu, right-click and select 'Surround with' and then pick 'directory'.